# Android - Set OnClickListener from another class

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-gridview

I have an `OnClickListener` here for my `GridView`:

```
public class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
     private final int position;  

public MyOnClickListener(int position)  
{  
    this.position = position;  
}  

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(position){
        case 0:
        Intent a = new Intent(v.getContext(), Weapons.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(a);
        break;
    //case 1, 2, etc...  

    }
}
```

How can I use this in another class? I have my `Category` class doing this:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.categoryGrid);
gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
gridview.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(this));
```

When I do this, the `(new MyOnClickListener(this));` line is underlined, saying I need to change `public MyOnClickListener(int position)` to `public MyOnClickListener(Category category)`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose what you want, do you want `MyOnClickListener` to accept in a `Category` object or an integer primitive?

The problem is your constructor accepts an int, but when you're making a `new MyOnClickListener` you pass off `this`, which points to the  `Category` instance, which is ***not*** an integer. If you don't want to pass off `this` pass of an integer (usually `0` is the starting index).

```
gridview.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(0));
```

eg

```
public MyOnClickListener(int position)  //requires an int
{  
    this.position = position;  
}
```

If you want do accept both in, make the constructor either accept in two arguments, or make two separate constructors.

```
Category category;
public MyOnClickListener(int position, Category category)  
{  
    this.position = position;  
    this.categoty = category;
}
```

Or

```
Category category;
public MyOnClickListener(Category category)  
{  
    this.position = 0;  
    this.categoty = category;
}
```

Also, GridViews should be using an `OnItemClickListener` instead since `OnClickListener` *won't* register the position. This means you need to change your class so it implements  `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`:

```
public class MyOnClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch(position){
      case 0:
        Intent a = new Intent(v.getContext(), Weapons.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(a);
        break;
        //case 1, 2, etc...  

    }
  }
}
```

then set it using using `setOnItemClickListener()`:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you said. What I'm doing with the listener is just making it so that each button in my GridView opens a different class. Another option is to add the MyOnClickListener code into the Category.java file, but I'm not sure how to implement that either. Thanks

Comment: @Deannakov you should be using an ItemClickListener for this, (see the edit) not a simple OnClickListener. Anyways, what isn't there to understand? your `MyOnClickListener` needs an `int`, you passed off a `Category` instance. Apples and cars, completely unrelated types.

Comment: Sorry. I was confused before you made all of your edits. Getting a crash that the log says `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.observerschool.MyOnClickListener cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener`

Comment: Change to `setOnItemClickListener()` instead of `setOnClickListener()` and make sure `MyOnClickListener` implements  `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` Optionally rename your class to better reflect its purpose. And definitely *do not* pass this class off as an `OnClickListener`.